# Update Salesforce opportunity on landing page submission

Tags: apex, trigger, opportunity

For full disclosure, I am not a developer, but I can dabble.

I want to set up a form on a landing page for clients to fill out. The form will contain custom fields that already exist on the opportunity page. On form submission, I want to populate the fields in that client's opportunity page with the values they filled out in the form.

Is this possible? I've been looking at https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_update.htm, but I'm not sure how to write to custom fields or if there's anything else I need to be concerned with.

I'm pretty much starting from the ground up with no knowledge of how to get started with apex, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!
Jess

Answer (score 1):

If you're not a developer, I would suggest you consider looking into Visual Workflows or Flows. Visual Workflows allow administrators to build simple user interfaces and guide users through forms and steps, very similar to the needs you are describing.

I love learning from the Salesforce workbooks because it allows me to really dig into a feature and see how it works in real scenarios. With that, please take a look at the Cloud Flow Designer Workbook:

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/workbook_flow/workbook_flow.pdf

Or for a broader overview of flows, there are dozens of resources out there, but I recommend starting with the documentation:

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=vpm_admin_flow_overview.htm&language=en_US

Comment: Thanks for linking this, greenstork. My company is actually still on the Salesforce Professional edition and I do not have access to workflows. This is an option we investigated, but it seemed that there were too many complications around getting a workflow set up properly to justify the price increase.

Comment: Your custom apex code is not available is Professional Edition either, so I'm afraid that the my recommended declarative and code-based solutions are both not available to you. Can you clarify, are you just looking to have external users fill out a form to populate the database? You might check out FormStack and FormAssembly who both have Salesforce integrations.

Comment: FormAssembly actually looks very promising - thanks!